# Adding JS functionality to the Publish button in wp-admin/post.php

Tags: posts, jquery, metabox

I've created a plugin with a new metabox in my post.php. It's working fine on it's own, but the problem is getting it to save it's values if the users choose to press the "Publish/Update/Save" in WordPress itself.

I have tried adding a JQuery function to the `#publish` item.

This way works, but it brings up an annoying "Are you sure you want to leave this page" because of the `window.location.reload()` which I can't have there.

```
                    $("#publish").click(function(e) {
                        //e.preventDefault();

                        // SM Data
                        var data = prepareData();

                        if(data.length !== 0) {
                            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
                                $.post( postdataAjax.ajaxurl, data[i] );
                            }
                        }

                        // WP Data
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "post.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: $("form#post").serialize(),
                            success: function(response,status) {
                                window.location.reload();
                            }
                        });

                        return true;
                    });
```

For this final solution I have tried using `window.onbeforeunload = null` and such, but not had any success with it.

This is the full function:

```
private function __construct() {
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_custom_metabox' ) );
}

public function add_custom_metabox() 
{
    $screens = array( 'post', 'page', 'landing' );
    foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {
        $this->set_plugin_slug();
        add_meta_box(
            '_meta',
            __( '###', $this->plugin_slug ),
            function( $post ) {
                global $slug;
                $html_code = _HTML_Code::get_instance();

                echo $html_code->generate_script_new_publication($post, $slug);
                echo $html_code->generate_script_list($post, $slug);
            }, $screen
        );
    }
}

...

public function generate_script_list($post, $slug) 
{ 
    global $wpdb;


    $mainTable = $wpdb->prefix.'esm';
    $data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $mainTable WHERE post_id = $post->ID ORDER BY publish_localtime ASC");
    $d_ids = array();
    foreach( $data as $item ) {
        $d_ids[] = $item->id;
    }

    ob_start();
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ( $ ) {
            "use strict";
            $(function () {
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    var $data_ids = <?php echo json_encode($d_ids); ?>;

                    function prepareData()
                    {
                        var $changed = parseInt($("#new-changed-new").val());

                        var data = [];
                        if( $changed == 1 ) {
                            $data_ids.push("new");
                        }

                        for(var i = 0; i < $data_ids.length; i++) {
                            var item_id = $data_ids[i];
                            var ch = parseInt($("#new-changed-"+item_id).val());

                            if(ch) {
                                var $selected_weekdays = '';
                                $("input[name=weekday-"+item_id+"]:checked").each( 
                                    function() { 
                                       $selected_weekdays += $(this).val()+';';
                                    }                               
                                );

                                var action = "update";
                                if(item_id == "new") {
                                    action = "create";
                                }

                                var d = new Date($("#one-time-date-"+item_id).datepicker("getDate"));
                                var d_local = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), $("#hour-"+item_id).val(), $("#minute-"+item_id).val(), 0));
                                var d_utc = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), $("#hour-"+item_id).val(), $("#minute-"+item_id).val(), 0);

                                //var d_from = new Date($range_from_year.val(), $range_from_month.val()-1, $range_from_day.val(), $hour.val(), $minute.val(), 0);
                                //var d_to = new Date($range_to_year.val(), $range_to_month.val()-1, $range_to_day.val(), $hour.val(), $minute.val(), 0);

                                var item = [
                                    { 'name': "_wpnonce", 'value' : postdataAjax.nonce },
                                    { 'name' : "action", 'value' : action },
                                    { 'name' : "item-id", 'value' : $("#item-id-"+item_id).val() },
                                    { 'name' : "post-id", 'value' : $("#post-id-"+item_id).val() },
                                    { 'name' : "channel", 'value' : $("#channel-"+item_id).val() },
                                    { 'name' : "text", 'value' : $("#text-"+item_id).val() },
                                    { 'name' : "image_url", 'value' : $("#filepath-"+item_id).val() },
                                    { 'name' : "local_time", 'value' : Math.round(d_local.getTime() / 1000), 'real' : d_local.toJSON() },
                                    { 'name' : "one_time_utc_time", 'value' : Math.round(d_utc.getTime() / 1000), 'real' : d_utc.toJSON() },
                                    //{ 'name' : "range_from_utc_time", 'value' : Math.round(d_from.getTime() / 1000), 'real' : d_from.toJSON() },
                                    //{ 'name' : "range_to_utc_time", 'value' : Math.round(d_to.getTime() / 1000), 'real' : d_to.toJSON() },
                                    { 'name' : "pattern", 'value' : $("#pattern-"+item_id).val() },
                                    { 'name' : "daily-pattern", 'value' : $("input[name=daily-pattern]:checked").val() },
                                    { 'name' : "daily-pattern-specified", 'value' : $("#daily-event-"+item_id+"-spec-day").val() },
                                    { 'name' : "weekly-pattern-specified", 'value' : $("#weekly-event-"+item_id+"-spec").val() },
                                    { 'name' : "weekday", 'value' : $selected_weekdays },
                                    { 'name' : "monthly-pattern", 'value' : $("input[name=monthly-pattern]:checked").val() },
                                    { 'name' : "monthly-pattern-1-day", 'value' : $("#monthly-event-"+item_id+"-pattern-1-day").val() },
                                    { 'name' : "monthly-pattern-1-month", 'value' : $("#monthly-event-"+item_id+"-pattern-1-month").val() },
                                    { 'name' : "monthly-pattern-2-select-num", 'value' : $("#monthly-event-"+item_id+"-pattern-2-select-num").val() },
                                    { 'name' : "monthly-pattern-2-select-weekday", 'value' : $("#monthly-event-"+item_id+"-pattern-2-select-weekday").val() },
                                    { 'name' : "monthly-pattern-2-month", 'value' : $("#monthly-event-"+item_id+"-pattern-2-month").val() },
                                    { 'name' : "yearly-pattern", 'value' : $("input[name=yearly-pattern]:checked").val() },
                                    { 'name' : "yearly-pattern-frequence", 'value' : $("#yearly-event-"+item_id+"-pattern-year").val() },
                                    { 'name' : "yearly-pattern-1-day", 'value' : $("#yearly-event-"+item_id+"-pattern-1-day").val() },
                                    { 'name' : "yearly-pattern-1-month", 'value' : $("#yearly-event-"+item_id+"-pattern-1-month").val() },
                                    { 'name' : "yearly-select-num", 'value' : $("#yearly-event-"+item_id+"-pattern-2-select-num").val() },
                                    { 'name' : "yearly-select-weekday", 'value' : $("#yearly-event-"+item_id+"-pattern-2-select-weekday").val() },
                                    { 'name' : "yearly-pattern-2-month", 'value' : $("#yearly-event-"+item_id+"-pattern-2-month").val() }
                                ];

                                switch( $("#channel-"+item_id).val() ) {
                                    case 'Facebook' :
                                        item.push({ 'name' : "publish_account", 'value' : $("input[name=facebook-publish-"+item_id+"]:checked").val() });
                                        break;
                                    case 'Twitter' :
                                        item.push({ 'name' : "publish_account", 'value' : $("input[name=twitter-publish-"+item_id+"]:checked").val() });
                                        break;
                                    default :
                                        break;
                                }

                                data.push(item);
                            }
                        }
                        return data;
                    }

                    $("form#post").submit(function(e) {
                        //e.preventDefault();

                        var data = prepareData();

                        if(data.length !== 0) {
                            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
                                $.post( postdataAjax.ajaxurl, data[i] );
                            }
                        }
                        /*$.ajax({
                            url: "post.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: $("form#post").serialize(),
                            success: function(response,status) {
                                //window.location.reload();
                            }
                        });*/

                        return true;
                    });
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <style>
    .sm-table {
        width: 100%;
    }
    </style>
    <table id="sm-table" class="sm-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:2%;text-align:center"></th>
                <th style="width:10%;text-align:left;"><?php _e('Channel', $slug); ?></th>
                <th style="width:43%;text-align:left;"><?php _e('Text', $slug); ?></th>
                <th style="width:30%;text-align:right;"><?php _e('Publish Date', $slug); ?></th>
                <th style="width:15%;text-align:right;"><?php _e('Actions', $slug); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php if( count($data) !== 0 ) : ?>
            <?php $i = 0; 
            foreach($data as $itemObj) : 
                $item = (array) $itemObj;
                $i++; 
            ?>
            <?php echo $this->generate_script_list_row($post, $item, $i, $slug); ?>
            <?php echo $this->generate_script_publication($post, $item, $slug); ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5"><?php _e('No publishing options found.', $slug); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
    $out = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $out;
}
```

So my question is, is what I'm trying to do achievable? How could I do it? An edit to an existing function or a total rewrite?

Comment: If you created a metabox with a plugin and it doesn't save then the best thing to do is to ask the plugin developer. It is hard to just guess what it does and why it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I developed a plugin that creates a metabox and I try to use this code within it.

Comment: then there are not enough detail what it is doing and why are you trying to use AJAX

Comment: If you're saving data from your metabox via ajax, that's fine. But make it compatible with default metabox flow so that your plugin works when 'publish' button is clicked.

Comment: I use AJAX because my plugin is not sending it's data to the wp_posts table, but to a table outside the regular table structure. What I need is for it to send the data even if the user don't press the "Save changes" button within my metabox, but chooses to do some changes in the main document, then "Update" the WordPress data there.

Comment: @HasinHayder How does one make the metabox compatible with the default metabox flow? I've used the add_meta_box function to create it. Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: @rnngau, have to say that your designe is strange, why only on publish and not on saving draft? In other words, why to hook on the button and not the frame submission?

Comment: @MarkKaplun I chose the first hook that seemed to work for me. But yeah, I guess I will have to create/use the same function for auto-draft and draft. Easier would be if I could attach it to the form submission itself.

Comment: Please add additional info as [edit] to the question - instead of commenting - to prevent a comment explosion. Also you might want to show your full code (incl. the AJAX part) and read questions about [tag:ajax] and meta boxes on this site to get a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using a `modal box` instead of `metabox`, forcing the users to finish editing the plugin data, before submitting the regular changes to WP.

```
    //add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_custom_metabox' ) );
    add_action( 'media_buttons_context', array($this, 'add_custom_media_buttons' ) );

    add_action( 'admin_footer', array($this, 'add_esm_edit' ) );
```

These were the lines that were added to the `__construct()`. Commented out the old one.

The code itself is a simple link and when clicking it, it brings up the `<div>` hiding in the `admin_footer`.